# How can you get Typeform file attachment submissions into Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, zapier, webflow, typeform

We have a Typeform that records entries for our job board, including a resume file attachment. We connected this to Salesforce natively and the entries are being recorded properly, except the file attachment which isn't natively supported. I searched for a solution and the only thing I saw recommended was Zapier. Set up a Zapier integration with the Typeform and have access to the following fields from the file:

**field_zzzzzzzzzz**: https://api.typeform.com/forms/xxxxx/responses/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/fields/xxxxxxxxxxxx/files/xxxxxxx-filename.pdf

Going to this url directly, even if logged into Typeform, returns the following raw json: {"code":"AUTHENTICATION_FAILED","description":"Authentication credentials not found on the Request Headers"}

This is the same url that you access from Typeform Results to download the file, but clicking from Typeform injects a Cookie that authorizes the file download.

**field_zzzzzzzzzz_file**: hydrate|||.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx--xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxx:xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxx|||hydrate

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just ended up doing a Google Drive integration and passing the URL of the file upload to SF, if anybody knows if this is possible without Drive let me know!

Answer (score 0):

In Zapier, when you receive data from a Typeform trigger, if the form response contains a file, you should see two things:

- File URL, which is a URL api.typeform.com....
- File Content, which is blob/binary

[image]

Depending on the action and its parameter, you can use one or the other.

The File URL requires authentication to access the file, as explained in the [API documentation](https://www.typeform.com/developers/responses/reference/get-a-file-from-a-response/).

On the Salesforce side, you need an intermediary step. First, upload the file with the `Create file` step. Then, use the reference of this file in the object.

If you need a public URL for the file, an alternative could be to do an "API request (beta)" Typeform action.
And use the api.typeform.com URL.
This will generate a new public URL that you could use in other actions.

[image: Zapier get response file typeform]